# Asp.net core 6 Docker OS

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

We have an ASP.NET Core Docker image built via the default `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base` in the Dockerfile.

We have a weekly build. Our vulnerability scan raises a different issue each build for low-level Debian libraries.
E.g. Week1: issue about `libraryA v1`. It is recommending us to update `libraryA` to `v2`.
But the following week, when we build a new Docker image, ASPNET automatically comes with `v2` of `libraryA`. We didn't even have to do something about `libraryA`. But then, new vulnerabilities are reported, which will then be automatically fixed in the coming weeks.

Is there a way to tell ASP to use a specific OS version?

From the ASPNET dockerhub,

> https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet/

These are the tags for Debian11:

```
6.0.13-bullseye-slim-amd64, 6.0-bullseye-slim-amd64, 6.0.13-bullseye-slim, 6.0-bullseye-slim, 6.0.13, 6.0
```

Our build last November was using `6.0.11` by checking the docker history of the image.
It reported some issue about krb5/libgssapi-krb5-2, recommending it to upgrade to version 1.18.3-6+**deb11u3**.
Our docker image last November was only using **deb11u2** when I `docker-exec`'ed into it.

Today (January), if I try the following `FROM` to force the specific ASPNET version, the library is automatically updated to **deb11u3** out of the box.

```
• FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.11 AS base
• FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.11-bullseye-slim-amd64 AS base
```

I am thinking of baselining a specific ASPNET or Debian version, and I will just manually address the vulnerability reports by using `apt-get` of those libraries. But from my testing above, it seems like Microsoft automatically updates the underlying OS even if I specify a specific version in the Dockerfile's `FROM`.

Any clue how to tell ASPNET to use a specific OS version? (Sorry Docker newbie here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspnet Dockerfiles aren't based on pinned versions of their dependencies, so even if you pin the aspnet version you want by using `6.0.13-bullseye-slim-amd64`, if Microsoft rebuild it and re-publish it, some of the underlying libraries might have been updated.

To completely pin what version of the image you want, you can use the digest in  your FROM statements instead of a tag. That way, you won't get any updates at all and will always point to the exact version of the image you want.

You use it like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet@sha256:5cf4aaa3fceb9bca683d56213873c0e418133a1ed36886a629bca266fb12e41b
```

You can find the digest by running `docker inspect image <image>`. The digest is in the 'RepoDigests' field. The digest is also printed when you do `docker pull`.

You should then add a comment in the Dockerfile about what tag the digest refers to, since that's not obvious anymore.

Let me add that this might not be a good idea to do. You're denying yourself security updates that could fix important vulnerabilities. It might be worth looking into how you can have a smooth workflow and also get these updates at the same time.

Comment: Thank you very much @Hans
Just to clarify, docker inspect image should be on the aspnet core image from the machine where I ran docker build last November. The RepoDigests from this machine will result to the outdated library from November.